flutter application failed to adjust button size
I am using following code snippet but I am unable to change size of buttons , they are occupying whole of screen . How can I control button size to smaller one ?
Widget buildButton(String buttonText) {
    return SizedBox(
      width: 150, // Adjust width as needed
      height: 500, // Adjust height as needed
      child: ElevatedButton(
        onPressed: () => buttonPress(buttonText),
        child: Text(
          buttonText,
          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 116), // Adjust font size if necessary
        ),
        style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
          shape: CircleBorder(),
          padding: EdgeInsets.zero, // Remove default padding
        ),
      ),
    );
  }


please share complete code

To reduce the button size, try removing the width and height properties from the SizedBox. If the issue continues, please share the full source code as requested by Mithun c.
